# Outlook iCalendar import - one hour shift with RRULE

Tags: outlook, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I have the following event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Event1
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230707T000000Z
DTSTAMP:20230402T182942Z
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20230327T103000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20230327T123000
LOCATION:Location1
SUMMARY:Description1
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

The times are set as 10:30-12:30, but when I import it to Outlook, the event is at 09:30-11:30 (pink on the screenshot below). But when I remove the `RRULE` line, the import times are correct (green on the screenshot).

I used the timezone definition from here for the calendar: https://www.tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Asia/index.html (`Jerusalem.ics`).

The full file is below.

[image]

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//tzurl.org//NONSGML Olson 2023b//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Jerusalem
LAST-MODIFIED:20230324T084302Z
TZURL:https://www.tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Asia/Jerusalem
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Jerusalem
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:IDT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
DTSTART:19700327T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1FR
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:IST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19701025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Event1
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20230707T000000Z
DTSTAMP:20230402T182942Z
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20230327T103000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Jerusalem:20230327T123000
LOCATION:Location1
SUMMARY:Description1
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```